# MySQL - Add a column to Temporary Tables from another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

I was wondering if you could add a column to a temporary table without the need to create a new one

Lets assume the following tables

```
Table1     |    Table2     |    Table3     |
Id  Atype  |    Id  Btype  |    Id  Ctype  |
1   A1     |    1   B1     |    1   C1     |
2   A2     |    2   B2     |    2   C2     |
3   A3     |    3   B3     |    3   C3     |
```

First i would like to create a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  temp_table ( INDEX(id) )
AS (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.atype , t2.btype
  FROM table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id);

Result:
temp_table
Id  Atype  Btype
1   A1     B1
2   A2     B2
3   A3     B3
```

Then i would like to add Ctype also in the temp table.
How can i do that?
Can i join in the current temp table or do i have to create a new temp table?

The end result i am looking is 1 temp table which looks like this:

```
Id  Atype  Btype  Ctype
1   A1     B1     C1
2   A2     B2     C2
3   A3     B3     C3
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use another `join`?

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.atype, t2.btype, t3.ctype
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t1.id = t3.id
```

If you actually want to modify the existing table, then:

alter table temp_table add ctype varchar(255);

```
update temp_table tt join
       table3 t3
       on tt.id = t3.id
    set tt.ctype = t3.ctype;
```

Comment: I agree with Gordon, but if you need to add a column to your temp table you should be able to do so with ALTER TABLE.

Comment: @RyanWilson . . . True.  But why not just create the temporary table that you want to begin with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will like to join "many" tables together which is a much easier process when you  join two or three each time. But while i was using the statement you recommended i received the following: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: @Gizazas . . . No, it is not "easier" to join 2 or 3 at a time.  Just write the query that you want and save the results in a temporary table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree with both points you made, I just thought I'd throw the ALTER TABLE command out there since he seemed to want to know about that from the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. Thank you very much that was very helpful! The statement does work when you disable that option. Sorry but i am beginner casual programmer and i try to understand how to build my database which is why is easier for me to write statement with 2 or 3 tables. Unfortunately  this will not do since with a tables of only 1k rows the temp table is created after 0.472sec, with only 1 temp table (no added columns) 0.110sec and with just the select statement 0.000 sec. I need to find another method to build my database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do when creating addin a 3th join()

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    temp_table ( INDEX(id) )
  AS (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.atype , t2.btype, t3.Ctype
    FROM table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    left join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.id);
```